# What is the easiest way to count my scala tests?

Tags: unit-testing, scala, scalatest

I want to be able to count all the scala tests in a directory or its sub-directory.

I'm using org.scalatest.  Can anyone suggest a fast way to do this?  Either from the test source, or from test output?

Comment: How do you run your unit tests? Maven? SBT? IDE? Do you use continuous integration server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Scalatest main page](http://scalatest.org/), the number of tests should be output when running the tests on the command line:

> $ scala -cp scalatest_2.9.0-2.0.M3.jar org.scalatest.run StackSpec
>   Run starting. Expected test count is: 2 
>   StackSpec:
>   A Stack 
>   - should pop values in last-in-first-out order
>   - should throw NoSuchElementException if an empty stack is popped
>   Run completed in 96 milliseconds.
>   Total number of tests run: 2